# Plotly: adding go.figure() to a subplot fails

Tags: python, plotly

Already been 2 hours that I am having issues to join different unique figures in a subplot.

Any idea why the following insn't working:

```
# MAIN FIGURE
fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1,
                    specs=[[{"rowspan": 3}],
                           [None],
                           [None],
                           [{}]])

# sub-FIGURE 1
candlestick = go.Candlestick(x = df.index,
                             open = df.open_BTC,
                             high = df.high_BTC,
                             low = df.low_BTC,
                             close = df.close_BTC)

# sub-FIGURE 2
# Filter data for conditional above/below 0 fillings
pos = df[i] >= 0
above = np.where(pos, df[i], np.nan)
below = np.where(pos, np.nan, df[i])
scatter1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=below, fill='tozeroy')
scatter2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=above, fill='tozeroy')
#... and other cool shit (but must be in fig2 only !)

fig2 = go.Figure(data=[scatter1, scatter2]) # <-- THIS PLOTS WELL !

# ADDING fig1 and fig2 IN SUBPLOT
fig.add_trace(candlestick, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig2, row=4, col=1) # <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK... WHY ?
```

Apparently, I am not understanding how to initialise figures correctly. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Here I am basically trying to add go.figure() to a subplots.

Answer (score 0):

Missunderstanding here as there are no such things.

I could make it the following way:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1,
                    specs=[[{"rowspan": 3}],
                           [None],
                           [None],
                           [{}]])

candlestick = go.Candlestick(x = df.index,
                             open = df.open_BTC,
                             high = df.high_BTC,
                             low = df.low_BTC,
                             close = df.close_BTC)

# Filter data
pos = df[i] >= 0
above = np.where(pos, df[i], np.nan)
below = np.where(pos, np.nan, df[i])
scatter1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=below, fill='tozeroy')
scatter2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=above, fill='tozeroy')

#fig2 = go.Figure(data=[scatter1, scatter2])

fig.add_trace(candlestick, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(scatter1, row=4, col=1) # <-- just add the elements at the correct place
fig.add_trace(scatter2, row=4, col=1)
```